# submartingale sequence is uniformly integrable

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

[image]

This is an exercise in Karatzas and Shreave's book on stochastic calculus. The $X_n$'s are real random variables on a probability space with $\sigma$ algebra $\mathscr{F}$.

I don't know what my uniformly bounding $L^1$ function should be. I appreciate any help.

Comment: @saz thank you! dunno why i didnt see that one